# Pyspark - Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o256.csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this error when I try save my data as csv.

Am using Pyspark 2.3.0 and JDK 8, but I got this error, can you helpe with this issue?

```
data.write.csv('dataset.csv')


Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3a2021aae4d9> in <module>
      3 # CSV
      4 
----> 5 data.write.csv('dataset.csv')
      6 
      7 # JSON

c:\Users\X\anaconda3\envs\X\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

c:\Users\X\anaconda3\envs\X\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o256.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

```
I tried with 

`data.write.csv('dataset.csv', mode="overwrite", sep=",", header=True)`
```

Comment: No, am got the same error

Comment: this is a very misleading question and there is not enough information to help. Please note that spark operates through lazy execution so the problem might not even originate due to the write operations, it is likely that something else before the write operation is causing it.